# Adding elements to Immutable List within forEach

Tags: immutable.js

I have an Immutable Map, where each key is an arbitrary category (these will be a List). I then have an array of strings that each category must have. If a specific category does not contain that string, it will be added to its respective List inside the Map.

```
const categories = new Map({
    cat1: new List(['animal', 'color']),
    cat2: new List(['animal']),
});

const missingKeys = new Map({
    cat1: new List(),
    cat2: new List(),
});

categories.keySeq().toArray().forEach((category) => {
    const keys = categories.get(category).keySeq().toArray();
    const requiredKeys = ['animal', 'color'];
    // loop through required keys and push any key that is not found
    // in the categories Map
    requiredKeys.forEach((key) => {
        if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            // add missing keys to respective category of `missingKeys`
            missingKeys.get(category).push(key)
        }
    });
});
```

I expect that after the loop completes, `categories` will be updated accordingly. However, when I try to console.log `categories`, the Map has not been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the whole "immutable" part of this library. The line

```
missingKeys.get(category).push(key)
```

*does not mutate `missingKeys`* or any of the lists it contains. It returns a new `List` with the missing key at the end.
If you want `missingKeys` to change, you need to reassign the variable:

```
missingKeys = missingKeys.update(category, keyList => keyList.push(key));
```

Don't forget to change that

---

As a side note, you're doing a lot of weird conversion with `keySeq` and `toArray`. What you have could be written more simply as:

```
const requiredKeys = ['animal', 'color'];
categories.forEach((keys, category) => {
  requiredKeys.forEach(requiredKey => {
    if (!keys.contains(key)) {
      missingKeys = missingKeys.update(category, keyList => keyList.push(key));
    }
  });
});
```

Or the even more idiomatic functional way:

```
const requiredKeys = List(['animal', 'color']);
const missingKeys = categories.map(keys =>
  requiredKeys.filter(key =>
    !keys.contains(key)))
```